My GraphQL Mutation doesn't resolve correctly to database
My GraphQL Mutation does not create a database entry. The problem seems to be caused by the handling of the Images array in the Article model.
In mypostgresql,  Image table is related to Article table(many to one)
Schema.prisma
model Article {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String
  content     String
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  published   Boolean   @default(false)
  featured    Boolean   @default(false) // New field for featured articles
  category    Category  @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId  Int
  author      Author    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    Int
  comments    Comment[]
  images      Image[]
  collection  Collection? @relation(fields: [collectionId], references: [id])
  collectionId Int?
}

model Image {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  url       String
  alt       String?
  article   Article  @relation(fields: [articleId], references: [id])
  articleId Int
}

For my GraphQL backend, I have the Article type, Image type, ImageInput input, and the mutation to createArticle.
TypeDefs
const typeDefs =  gql`
input ImageInput {
  url: String
  alt: String
}

type Mutation {
  createArticle(
    title: String!, 
    content: String!, 
    categoryId: Int!, 
    authorId: Int!, 
    featured: Boolean, 
    published: Boolean,
    images: [ImageInput]  
  ): Article!
}

type Article {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  createdAt: String!
  updatedAt: String!
  published: Boolean!
  featured: Boolean!
  category: Category!
  categoryId: Int!
  author: Author!
  authorId: Int!
  comments: [Comment]
  images: [Image]
  collection: Collection
  collectionId: Int
}

type Image {
  id: Int!
  url: String!
  alt: String
  article: Article!
  articleId: Int!
}
`

This is where the problem seems to lie: creating images (or no images) along with the article. I have addressed handling empty image array but cannot figure out why does the problem persist.
Resolver
const Mutation = {
  createArticle: async (_, args, { prisma }) => {
    const { title, content, categoryId, authorId, featured, published, images, collectionId } = args;
    const validImages = images && images.length > 0 ? images.filter(img => img.url && img.url.trim() !== '') : [];
    return await prisma.article.create({
      data: {
        title,
        content,
        featured,
        published,
        category: {
          connect: { id: parseInt(categoryId) }
        },
        author: {
          connect: { id: parseInt(authorId) }
        },
        images: validImages.map(img => ({
          create: {
            url: img.url,
            alt: img.alt || ""
          }
        })),
        collection: collectionId ? { connect: { id: parseInt(collectionId) } } : undefined
      }
    });
  },}

Client Side GraphQL
the client side GraphQL mutation, and the relevant code (form handling) in my React (Next JS) component.
const CREATE_ARTICLE = gql`
mutation CreateArticle($title: String!, $content: String!, $categoryId: Int!, $authorId: Int!, $featured: Boolean!, $published: Boolean!, $images: [ImageInput!]) {
    createArticle(title: $title, content: $content, categoryId: $categoryId, authorId: $authorId, featured: $featured, published: $published, images: $images) {
      id
      title
      images {
        id
        url
        alt
      }
    }
  }
  
`;

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const filteredImages = formData.images.filter(image => image.imageUrl.trim() !== '');
        try {
            const categoryId = formData.categoryId ? parseInt(formData.categoryId) : null;
            const authorId = formData.authorId ? parseInt(formData.authorId) : null;
            const collectionId = formData.collectionId ? parseInt(formData.collectionId) : null; // Handle empty string by converting to null

            const variables = {
                title: formData.title,
                content: formData.content,
                categoryId, // Ensure this is either a valid integer or null
                authorId, // Ensure this is either a valid integer or null
                featured: formData.featured,
                published: formData.published,
                images: filteredImages.map(image => ({
                    url: image.imageUrl,
                    alt: image.imageAlt || undefined // Use undefined for no alt text
                })),
                collectionId // This will now be null if empty, which should be acceptable if the field is optional
            };

            console.log('Submitting with data:', variables);
            
            const response = await createArticle({ variables: variables });

            console.log('Article creation response:', response);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Failed to add article');
            console.error("Error creating an article:", err);
        }
    };

